# Getting list with max value from a list of lists in Racket

Tags: arrays, list, racket

Given a list of lists of integers, I need this program in racket to display the list which contains the largest value.

For example:

> [[2000, 4, 1000, 8], [2, 7, 810, 20], [19, 101, 4, 9]],

should display

> [2000, 4, 100, 8]

as a result since 2000 is the largest value.

However, the following program is giving me the error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '((28 14 32) (24 14 100))
  arguments...: [none]
```

And I'm not sure why. Could somebody help? I'm quite new to racket

```
#lang racket

(define (maxlist)
  (let loop((largest(cdr list))(m (car list)))
    (cond
      [(empty? list) m]
      [(> (car list) m) (loop (cdr list)(car list))]
      [else (loop (cdr list) m)])))

(define v1 (list (list 28 14 32) (list 24 14 100)))

maxlist(v1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty list case leads to an error, if the list has just one sub-list, then that sub-list is the max-sub-list. Otherwise, we find the max-sub-list of the rest of the list using a recursive call and compare the max element in that list with the max element in the first sub-list, based on which has a bigger max element, we decide if the max-sub-list is the first sub-list or the result of the recursive call.

```
#lang racket

; (maxlist : (-> (Listof (Listof Number)) (Listof Number)))
; sublist that contains the largest number
(define (maxlist lolon)
  (cond [(empty? lolon) (error "'() does not have \"max\"-sublist")]
        [(empty? (rest lolon)) (first lolon)]
        [else
         (let ([max-rst (maxlist (rest lolon))])
           (if (> (apply max max-rst) (apply max (first lolon)))
               max-rst
               (first lolon)))]))

(maxlist '((2000 4 1000 8) (2 7 810 20) (19 101 4 9)))
; => '(2000 4 1000 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#lang racket

;; write a function returning from two lists the list with the bigger element 
(define (greater-list l1 l2)
  (if (> (apply max l1) (apply max l2)) l1 l2))

;; apply this function throughout a lol (list of lists) 
;; - and it will return the max-list amongst the lists
(define (maxlist lol)
  (foldl greater-list '() lol))
```